# Plugin contact form with date and time input exists in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Im new in wordpress and want to ask, if a plugin exists which have a contact form with date and time input. If a user choose a date and time, the date and time are not shown in the input field anymore.

Its something like a scheduler. I have found a plugin that is similar :

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/meeting-scheduler-by-vcita/

But this plugin is calender instead of a contact form.

Comment: what exactly you want? a scheduler? or a form with date and time input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want **Contact Form Plugin** with date and time input there is a plugin named [FormCraft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/formcraft-form-builder/) with advanced UI and backend submission view.
2. If you want a scheduler there are [Scheduler Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=Appointment%20Booking%20) as well

**Update**

For contact form with scheduler functionality you can try this [Birch Scheduler Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/birchschedule/) it will delete the previous appointed time slot, i think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: ah okay thank you. The function with the date/time delete after a user choose the time must be implement with javascript or is there a option in the plugin ? Sorry i am totally new in wordpress :D

Comment: seems like you want a schedular with contact form, what i understand is : you want to disable that selected time slot your user choose to meet you or schedule meeting whatever it is... right?

Comment: i updated my answer, this plugin will help you do what you want.